# Tridion integration framework - Expanding a ECL folder does not call ListFolderService method

Tags: ecl-connector

I am re-writing the ECL connector using the Tridion integration framework. I installed the default project template and I installed the out of the box implementation of the demo connector that comes with the project template.

Below is the image of the connector's start method's code and the connector in Tridion. My question is that expanding the ECL folder (for example folder1 in this case) calls the GetFolderService and ListFileService methods and these method in turn returns the current Folder and List of files, but there is no code block here that is responsible for returning the list of folders that are children of the current folder.

Is it ListFileService that should return the child folders also? If so then it would make sense to rename it to ListChildService.

[image]

[image]

Thanks.